# new bower version and bower packages in asp.core

Tags: asp.net-core, bower

few moths ago i create project on asp.core 2.0  framework ,install bower and few bowers packages . Everything was fine until I migrate to core 2.1 , update bower version and  tried to update installed packages to upper version and start to getting 502 error.
Then I found that to fix 502 error I should change code in  bowerrc.json so i change it from

```
   { 
      "directory": "wwwroot/lib" 
    }
```

To

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"

}
```

After this change update and installing packages works fine but now instead of  `root/wwwroot/lib`  they are in `root/bower-components`   so the old links as `"~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"` doesn't work anymore.

Is there any good solution to this problem except :

1. manually coping file from bower-component to wwwroot/lib
2. changing in every view path to necessary js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to choose between either `directory` or `registry`: You can have both in a single JSON object, like so:

```json
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib",
    "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

The `directory` property specifies where to install the bower libraries, which defaults to `bower_components`.

---

You'll likely see that bower is no longer recommended for front-end libraries. It should still work with the changes you've made, but see [here](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/) for more information about migration.